# Select multiple counts of result from subquery, based on where statements?

Tags: sql

So, I select from a subquery, and display a count of those rows based on if it has a value in a value in a column created (using a where statement).

I want to create a query that returns several counts based on different where statements.

My table has two columns: ID1 and abc2.

```
select count(*) from
(
select `id1`, count(distinct(`abc2`)) as total_abc
from TABLE
where `id1` != 'Unknown' and `abc2` != 'NULL'
group by `id1`
order by total_abc desc
)
where total_abc = 1




select count(*) from
(
select `id1`, count(distinct(`abc2`)) as total_abc
from TABLE
where `id1` != 'Unknown' and `abc2` != 'NULL'
group by `id1`
order by total_abc desc
)
where total_abc = 2





select count(*) from
(
select `id1`, count(distinct(`abc2`)) as total_abc
from TABLE
where `id1` != 'Unknown' and `abc2` != 'NULL'
group by `id1`
order by total_abc desc
)
where total_abc = 3
```

Desired results just combine these several queries:

```
count1 | count2 | count3
__________________________
123    | 222     | 34567
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database ou are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select
    count(case when num_vals = 1 then 1 end) as val_1,
    count(case when num_vals = 2 then 1 end) as val_2,
    count(case when num_vals = 3 then 1 end) as val_3
from
(
    select id1, count(distinct abc2) as num_vals
    from TABLE
    where id1 <> 'Unknown' and abc2 <> 'NULL'
    group by id1
) t;
```

You seem to want the values in columns.  I would prefer them in rows:

```
select num_vals, count(*)
from (select id1, count(distinct abc2) as num_vals
      from TABLE
      where id1 <> 'Unknown' and abc2 <> 'NULL'
      group by id1
     ) t
group by num_vals
order by num_vals;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your subqueries are the exact same, you can do something like this

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN total_abc = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count1
SUM(CASE WHEN total_abc = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count2
SUM(CASE WHEN total_abc = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count3
 from
(
select `id1`, count(distinct(`abc2`)) as total_abc
from TABLE
where `id1` != 'Unknown' and `abc2` != 'NULL'
group by `id1`
order by total_abc desc
)
where total_abc IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to do this for all values though? So 1-infinity?

Comment: Probably quite hard to do if you want it returned in columns, unless you pivot. I suggest looking at Gordon's answer above where he uses grouping to achieve the same but in rows.